ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nnutils-pytorch-cuda (from versions: none)

I am having problems installing nnutils-pytorch-cuda for days... This is preventing me from correctly installing the PyLaia library (https://github.com/jpuigcerver/PyLaia).
*Requirements
*Python: 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8 (tested with version 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8).
PyTorch >= 1.6.0 (tested with version 1.6.0).
C++14 compiler (tested with GCC 7.5.0).
For GPU support: CUDA Toolkit.
https://pypi.org/project/nnutils-pytorch-cuda/
I am complying with the requirements mentioned, but I am unable to complete the installation.
How can I complete the installation successfully?
